# Uploaded jpg from React Native iOS app to Azure Blob Storage will not open but contains base64 data

Tags: javascript, react-native, azure, azure-blob-storage, jpeg

I'm trying to create a screen on a React Native mobile app that allows a user to upload and crop a profile pic, and then upload to Azure blob storage.

I struggled with this as lots of sites pointed to react-native-fs but when I tried to implement that I always got an error so I gave up.

I can get the file to upload to Azure Blob Storage. If I uploaded a text file it works perfectly and is readable.  When I tried to do this with a jpg the file is uploaded but it is not readable.  However, if I change the extension to .txt and open it in notepad I can copy the content and paste it into a base64 to image conversion website then it works perfectly.

I feel like I'm so close but can't make the final hurdle.   Here is the code ...

```
  const saveFile = async () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const dateString = currentDate.toUTCString();

    // read the contents of the selectedImage file
    const response = await fetch(selectedImage);
    const fileData = await response.blob();
    const base64Data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileData);
      // reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result.split(",")[1]);
      reader.onload = () =>
        resolve(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${reader.result.split(",")[1]}`);

      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });

    var config = {
      method: "put",
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      url: "https://clubmanpics.blob.core.windows.net/playerpics/newfile13.jpg",
      headers: {
        "x-ms-version": "2017-11-09",
        "x-ms-date": dateString,
        "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
        "Content-Length": base64Data.length,
        "Content-Encoding": "base64",
      },
      data: Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64"),
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I've tried the code above with and without the "Content-Encoding": "base64" string but no luck.

Comment: This means your file is not in the image format, but instead a text file with base 64 encoded data. So, to make it work you have to upload the file as bytes instead of base64.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I have reproed the issue using react only not react native (due to lack of infrastructure)

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

You can follow this [Document](https://stuarttottle.medium.com/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-react-34f37805fdfc#:%7E:text=Upload%20to%20Azure%20Blob%20Storage%20with%20React%201,5%20Creating%20a%20component%20to%20display%20upload%20progress) to setup infrastructure to upload jpg files using react application.

In that code, you need to change the code in **`SasGeneratorService.ts`**.

First, create a JSON file and add the storage account URL and SAS token as below:

```
{"storageUri":"https://< storageaccountname >.blob.core.windows.net","storageAccessToken":"< Your Storage account SAS token>"}
```

Once, You edited please save it as a JSON file in the blob storage and copy the URL of the file and paste it in **`SasGeneratorService.ts`**

**Code:**

```
import { Axios } from 'axios-observable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BlobStorageRequest } from '../types/azure-storage';

export class SasGeneratorService {
  getSasToken(): Observable<BlobStorageRequest> {
    return Axios.get<BlobStorageRequest>(
      'https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/demo.json'
    ).pipe(map(res => res.data));
  }
}
```

Now, if run the code with **`npm start`** it will navigate to the browser(Localhost:3000) and you can upload the image(jpg) via the browser.

**Browser:**
[image]

**Portal:**

In the portal, you can see the uploaded image via react application.

[image]

Make sure your **`CORS`** policy is enabled to run under one domain to access resources.

**Reference:**
[stottle-uk/stottle-react-blob-storage (github.com)](https://github.com/stottle-uk/stottle-react-blob-storage)